# Elasticsearch: failed to create query:

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to search specific fields in a nested json. But elasticsearch keeps giving query error.

```
results= es.search(index="zimbo",doc_type="limon",body={

    "query" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : <title>,
            "query" : {
                "nested" : {
                    "path" :  <title>,
                    "query" :  {
                        "nested" : {
                            "path" :  "SUCCESS",
                            "query" :  {
                                "nested" : {
                                    "path" :  <title>,
                                    "query" :  {
                                        "bool" : {
                                            "must" : [
                                                { "match" : { <title> : "UI" } }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output of only UI ones, but it gives the following error:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400,
>   'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to create query:

---

I used dummy data to see if it works. Still does not work. Here its code, having same error.

```
results= es.search(index="cido",doc_type="rest",body={
    "query" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "restaurants",
            "query" : {
                "nested" : {
                    "path" :  "reviews",
                    "query" :  {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "term" : { "name" : "Steve" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here its mapping:

```
{"cido":{
  "mappings":{
    "rest":{
     "properties":{
       "restaurants":{
         "properties":{
            "address":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields": { 
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
              }
            },
            "cuisine_type":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
              }
            },
            "id":{
              "type":"long"
            },
            "latlng":{
              "properties":{
                "lat":{
                  "type":"float"},
                "lng":{"type":"float"}
              }
            },
            "name":{
              "type":"text",
              "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                }
              },
              "neighborhood":{
                "type":"text",
                "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                    "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                }
              },
              "operating_hours":{
                "properties":{
                  "Friday":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "fields":{
                      "keyword":{
                        "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                    }
                  },
                  "Monday":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "fields":{"keyword":{
                      "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                    }
                  },
                  "Saturday":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "fields":{"keyword":{
                      "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                    }
                  },
                  "Sunday":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "fields":{"keyword":{
                      "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                    }
                  },
                  "Thursday":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "fields":{
                      "keyword":{
                        "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                    }
                  },
                  "Tuesday":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                       "keyword":{
                         "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                     }
                  },
                  "Wednesday":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "fields":{
                      "keyword":{
                        "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "photograph":{
                "type":"text",
                  "fields":{
                    "keyword":{
                      "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                  }
                },
              "reviews":{
                "properties":{
                  "comments":{
                    "type":"text",
                      "fields":{
                        "keyword":{ 
                          "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                      }
                  },
                  "date":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "fields":{
                       "keyword":{
                         "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                    }
                  },
                  "name":{
                    "type":"text",
                    "fields":{
                      "keyword":{
                        "type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}
                    }
                  },
                  "rating":{
                    "type":"long"}
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Then post the error too. Also can try to copy query on elastic dev_tools

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.

Comment: Can you add mapping and sample data

Comment: As I cannot share the data I use I will share the dummy data. Thank you.